# Extracting City and Zipcode from String in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, match

I need a fast generic way in PHP to extract the City and Zipcode (when available) information from an input string.

The string can be of the following forms

1. $input_str = "123 Main Street, New Haven, CT";
2. $input_str = "123 Main Street, New Haven, CT 06510";
3. $input_str = "New Haven, CT, United States";
4. $input_str = "New Haven, CT 06510";

I was thinking that for (1) & (3) atleast I could explode the input string with "," and then loop thru the array to find a 2 digit STATE character and ignore it. But I'm stuck beyond this point.

```
$search_values = explode(',' ,$input_str);
foreach($search_values as $search)
{
    $trim_search = trim($search);   // Remove any trailing white spaces

    // If the 2 digit State is provided without Zipcode, ignore it
    if (strlen($trim_search) == 2)
    {
        //echo 'Ignoring State Without Zipcode: ' . $search . '<br>';
        continue;
    }

    ...
```

Comment: How well formed are the inputs guaranteed to be?  Usually addresses, well, aren't guaranteed to be much of anything.  User-inputted address strings have about as much variety and edge cases as anything.  You might have more luck taking the whole string as-is, sending it to a geocoding service, and getting back structured data from which you can easily extract individual elements.

Comment: Thanks @David The inputs are pretty well formed in my case. So its not entirely an open ended problem. But you make an interesting point about the geocoding service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not the greatest with regex, but here's a shot in finding a 2 character state with or without a zip code.

Regex:  `(([A-Z]{2})|[0-9]{5})+`

[Fiddle](http://refiddle.co/1uv3)

However, if you want to match only when the state AND zip code are together, take a look at this:
Regex: `(([A-Z]{2})(\s*[0-9]{5}))+`

[Fiddle](http://refiddle.co/1uv4)

```
class Extract  {
    
    private $_string;
    
    private $_sections = array();
    
    private $_output = array();
        
    private $_found = array();
    
    private $_original_string;
    
    private $_countries = array (
        'United States',
        'Canada',
        'Mexico',
        'France',
        'Belgium',
        'United Kingdom',
        'Sweden',
        'Denmark',
        'Spain',
        'Australia',
        'Austria',
        'Italy',
        'Netherlands'
    );
    
    private $_zipcon = array();
    
    private $ZIPREG = array(
        "United States"=>"^\d{5}([\-]?\d{4})?$",
        "United Kingdom"=>"^(GIR|[A-Z]\d[A-Z\d]??|[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z\d]??)[ ]??(\d[A-Z]{2})$",
        "Germany"=>"\b((?:0[1-46-9]\d{3})|(?:[1-357-9]\d{4})|(?:[4][0-24-9]\d{3})|(?:[6][013-9]\d{3}))\b",
        "Canada"=>"^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\s*(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$",
        "France"=>"^(F-)?((2[A|B])|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{3}$",
        "Italy"=>"^(V-|I-)?[0-9]{5}$",
        "Australia"=>"^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1345689][0-9]{3})|(2[0-8][0-9]{2})|(290[0-9])|(291[0-4])|(7[0-4][0-9]{2})|(7[8-9][0-9]{2})$",
        "Netherlands"=>"^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?([a-zA-Z]{2})?$",
        "Spain"=>"^([1-9]{2}|[0-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9])[0-9]{3}$",
        "Denmark"=>"^([D-d][K-k])?( |-)?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$",
        "Sweden"=>"^(s-|S-){0,1}[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{2}$",
        "Belgium"=>"^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$"
    ); // thanks to http://www.pixelenvision.com/1708/zip-postal-code-validation-regex-php-code-for-12-countries/
    
    public function __construct($string) {

        $this->_output = array (
        
            "state" => "",
            "city" => "",
            "country" => "",
            "zip" => "",
            "street" =>"",
            "number" => ""
        );
        $this->_original_string = $string;
        $this->_string = $this->normalize(trim($string));
        
        
        // create an array of patterns in order to extract zip code using the country list we already have
        foreach($this->ZIPREG as $country => $pattern) {
            $this->_zipcon[] = $pattern = preg_replace( array("/\^/","/\\$/"),array("",""), $pattern);
        }
    
        $this->init();

    }
    
    protected function init() {
        
        $this->getData(); // get data that can be found without breaking up the string.
        
        $this->_sections = array_filter(explode(',', trim($this->_string)));  // split each section

        if(!empty($this->_sections)) {
            foreach($this->_sections as $i => $d) {
                $d = preg_replace(array("/\s+/", "/\s([?.!])/"),  array(" ","$1"), $d ); 
                $this->_sections[$i] = trim($this->normalize($d));  // normalize strin to have one spacing between each word
            }
        } else {
            $this->_sections[] = $this->_string;    
        }       
        
        // try to match what's missing with has already been found
        $notFound = $this->getNotFound();
        if(count($notFound)==1 && count($this->_found)>1) {
            $found = $this->getFound();
            foreach($found as $string) {
                $notFound[0] = preg_replace("/$string/i", "", $notFound[0]);
            }
            $this->_output["city"] = $notFound[0];
            $this->_found[] = $this->_output["city"];
            $this->remove($this->_output["city"]);
        }   
    }
    
    public function getSections() {
        return $this->_sections;
    }   
    
    protected function normalize($string) {
        $string = preg_replace(array("/\s+/", "/\s([?.!])/"),  array(" ","$1"), trim($string));
        return $string;
    }
    
    protected function country_from_zip($zip) {
        $found = "";
        foreach($this->ZIPREG as $country => $pattern) {
            if(preg_match ("/".$pattern."/", $zip)) {
                $found = $country;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $found;
    }
    
    protected function getData() {
        $container = array();
        // extract zip code only when present beside state, or else five digits are meaningless
        
        if(preg_match ("/[A-Z]{2,}\s*(".implode('|', $this->_zipcon).")/", $this->_string) ){
            preg_match ("/[A-Z]{2,}\s*(".implode('|', $this->_zipcon).")/", $this->_string, $container["state_zip"]);

            $this->_output["state"] = $container["state_zip"][0];
            $this->_output["zip"] = $container["state_zip"][1];
            $this->_found[] = $this->_output["state"] . " ". $this->_output["zip"];
            // remove from string once found
            $this->remove($this->_output["zip"]);   
            $this->remove($this->_output["state"]);
            
            // check to see if we can find the country just by inputting zip code
            if($this->_output["zip"]!="" ) {
                $country = $this->country_from_zip($this->_output["zip"]);
                $this->_output["country"] = $country;
                $this->_found[] = $this->_output["country"];
                $this->remove($this->_output["country"]);
            }
        } 
        
        if(preg_match ("/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/", $this->_string)) {
            preg_match ("/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/", $this->_string, $container["state"]);  
            $this->_output["state"] = $container["state"][0];
            $this->_found[] = $this->_output['state'];
            $this->remove($this->_output["state"]);
        }

        // if we weren't able to find a country based on the zip code, use the one provided (if provided)
        if($this->_output["country"] == "" && preg_match("/(". implode('|',$this->_countries)  . ")/i", $this->_string) ){
            preg_match ("/(". implode('|',$this->_countries)  . ")/i", $this->_string, $container["country"]);
            $this->_output["country"] = $container["country"][0];
            $this->_found[] = $this->_output['country'];
            $this->remove($this->_output["country"]);
        }   
            
        if(preg_match ("/([0-9]{1,})\s+([.\\-a-zA-Z\s*]{1,})/", $this->_string) ){
            preg_match ("/([0-9]{1,})\s+([.\\-a-zA-Z\s*]{1,})/", $this->_string, $container["address"]);
            $this->_output["number"] = $container["address"][1];
            $this->_output["street"] = $container["address"][2];
            $this->_found[] = $this->_output["number"] . " ". $this->_output["street"];
            $this->remove($this->_output["number"]);
            $this->remove($this->_output["street"]);
        }       
        
        
        //echo $this->_string;
    }
    
    /* remove from string in order to make it easier to find missing this */
    protected function remove($string, $case_sensitive = false) {
        $s = ($case_sensitive==false ? "i" : "");
        $this->_string = preg_replace("/".$string."/$s", "", $this->_string);
    }

    public function getNotFound() {
        return array_values(array_filter(array_diff($this->_sections, $this->_found)));
    }
    
    public function getFound() {
        return $this->_found;   
    }

    /* outputs a readable string with all items found */
    public function toString() {
        $output = $this->getOutput();
        $string = "Original string: [ ".$this->_original_string.' ] ---- New string: [ '. $this->_string. ' ]<br>';
        foreach($output as $type => $data) {
            $string .= "-".$type . ": " . $data. '<br>';    
        }   
        return $string;
    }
    
    /* return the final output as an array */
    public function getOutput() {
        return $this->_output;  
    }   
    
}



$array = array();
$array[0] = "123 Main Street, New Haven, CT 06518";
$array[1] = "123 Main Street, New Haven, CT";
$array[2] = "123 Main Street, New Haven,                            CT 06511";
$array[3] = "New Haven,CT 66554, United States";
$array[4] = "New Haven, CT06513";
$array[5] = "06513";
$array[6] = "123 Main    Street, New Haven CT 06518, united states";

$array[7] = "1253 McGill College, Montreal, QC H3B 2Y5"; // google Montreal  / Canada
$array[8] = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043"; // google CA  / US
$array[9] = "20 West Kinzie St., Chicago, IL 60654"; // google IL / US
$array[10] = "405 Rue Sainte-Catherine Est, Montreal, QC"; // Montreal address shows hyphened street names
$array[11] = "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009"; // google Australia


foreach($array as $string) {
    $a = new Extract($string);

    echo $a->toString().'<br>'; 
}
```

Using the example from the code above it should output:

```
Original string: [ 123 Main Street, New Haven, CT 06518 ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: CT
-city: New Haven
-country: United States
-zip: 06518
-street: Main Street
-number: 123

Original string: [ 123 Main Street, New Haven, CT ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: CT
-city: New Haven
-country: 
-zip: 
-street: Main Street
-number: 123

Original string: [ 123 Main Street, New Haven, CT 06511 ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: CT
-city: New Haven
-country: United States
-zip: 06511
-street: Main Street
-number: 123

Original string: [ New Haven,CT 66554, United States ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: CT
-city: New Haven
-country: United States
-zip: 66554
-street: 
-number: 

Original string: [ New Haven, CT06513 ] ---- New string: [ , ]
-state: CT
-city: New Haven
-country: United States
-zip: 06513
-street: 
-number: 

Original string: [ 06513 ] ---- New string: [ 06513 ]
-state: 
-city: 
-country: 
-zip: 
-street: 
-number: 

Original string: [ 123 Main Street, New Haven CT 06518, united states ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: CT
-city: New Haven
-country: United States
-zip: 06518
-street: Main Street
-number: 123

Original string: [ 1253 McGill College, Montreal, QC H3B 2Y5 ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: QC
-city: Montreal
-country: Canada
-zip: H3B 2Y5
-street: McGill College
-number: 1253

Original string: [ 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043 ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: CA
-city: Mountain View
-country: United States
-zip: 94043
-street: Amphitheatre Parkway
-number: 1600

Original string: [ 20 West Kinzie St., Chicago, IL 60654 ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: IL
-city: Chicago
-country: United States
-zip: 60654
-street: West Kinzie St.
-number: 20

Original string: [ 405 Rue Sainte-Catherine Est, Montreal, QC ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: QC
-city: Montreal
-country: 
-zip: 
-street: Rue Sainte-Catherine Est
-number: 405

Original string: [ 48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009 ] ---- New string: [ , , ]
-state: NSW
-city: Pyrmont
-country: Australia
-zip: 2009
-street: Pirrama Road
-number: 48
```

If you want to extract the actual stored values so you can use. You need to call the `getOutput()`. This will return an array with all the values necessary. If we take the first address on our list and output its values using this method, it should output:

```
Array
(
    [state] => CT
    [city] => New Haven
    [country] => United States
    [zip] => 06518
    [street] => Main Street
    [number] => 123
)
```

Please note that this class can be greatly optimized and improved. This is what I came up within the hour, so I cannot guarantee it will work for all types of inputs. In essence, you must make sure the user at least makes an effort in using commas to separate parts of the address. You also want to make sure that a capitalized state is provided and a valid five digit zip code.

**A few rules**

1. In order to extract a zip code, a valid 2 character state must be provided with a valid zip code beside it. Example:  CT 06510. Without the state, simply inputting five digits is meaningless since there can also be five digits in the street number. (Cannot differentiate between the two).
2. Street and Number can only be extracted if there is a number and a word(s) provided in sequence. Example: `123 Main Street`. It also must be separated by a comma or it will capture all the words after the number. For example, `123 Main Street New Haven, CT 06518`, the code will the that the street and number is `123 Main Street New Haven` rather than `123 Main Street`.
3. Simply inputting a five digit zip code will not work.
4. If a country is not given, it will guess the country provided that there is a valid zip code (see list of zip-codes and their respective countries above).
5. <s>It assumes that no hyphens will be provided (especially for city names). This can be modified later on. (Regex needs to be modified to accommodate hyphenated words for both city and street names).</s>  (fixed)
6. The bottom line is that you can do a lot more if you have some time to change and modify the regular expressions and customize this accordingly.

I would strongly suggest you to use forms (in case you don't already have) in order to easily capture the address provided in inputs. It'll probably make your life a lot easier.

**Quick use**

```
$Extract = new Extract("123 Main Street, New Haven, CT 06518");
$foundValues = $Extract->getOutput();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It certainly helps. But the complete generic solution still eludes me.

Comment: @rogerb So what exactly is it that you wish to do? Do you want to extract the state and zip cope and store them in variables somewhere?

Comment: Yes. Actually its the City and Zipcode that I want to extract - and store in variables. The zipcode will always be 5 digits but the city can be 1 word (e.g. Milford) or multiple words (e.g. New Haven).

Comment: @rogerb I just re-edited my answer. It extracts the zip code and the two character state. As for the city, that'll be a little trickier since you'd have to distinguish words coming from the country and the ones coming from the city. I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: Thanks a lot pal! That looks promising. I look forward to your solution to extract the city. Thanks again!

Comment: @rogerb Check out the new edit. I've provided you with a class that'll do the job. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Dimitri - This is terrific. Thanks for taking the time to do this. I have read thru all your assumptions and they are valid. I think this solution should work. I dont have a way to test this now but I will tonight and accept this answer once I do. Thanks again!

Comment: @rogerb You're welcome. I haven't really tested out thoroughly  so there might a few things that require tweaking and modifying. If I have some time I'll look through it some more. This should get you started.

Comment: Dimitri - This works just great. I just tested it and everything works perfectly. Thanks for making the additional mods to allow hyphens for city. Really appreciate it.. Stellar work!

Comment: @rogerb you're welcome! If ever I get a chance to tidy it and make it more official, I'll keep you posted! Enjoy.

Comment: Added this at the end of init function because it was not working for city sometimes. Other than it perfect class :) thanks

   if($this->_output["city"]=="")
   {
    $exploded = explode(",", substr($this->_original_string, 0, strpos($this->_original_string, $this->_output["state"])-1));
    // print_r($exploded);
    $this->_output["city"] = end(array_filter($exploded));
    if($this->_output["city"]=="")
    {
     $this->_output["city"] = $this->_sections[1];
    }
   }