# How To Seperate STATE, CITY and ZIPCODE when cases are change

Tags: php

I found the same question but that's not very helpful because that is not working in many cases. So, I'm writing this question may be somebody have a better solution for it.

These are my addresses example.

```
[0] => "Skattkarr Varmland SE-65671" //Sweden
[1] => "Rayleigh , Essex SS6 8YJ" //UK
[2] => "Horgen, Zürich 8810" //Switzerland
[3] => "Edmonton Alberta T5A 2L8" //Canada
[4] => "REDDING, CA 96003" //USA
[5] => "New York, NY 96003" //USA
[6] => "New York NY 96003" //USA
```

I tried alot, but for many cases I'm getting failed.
I can pass 2 or 3 but I can't pass for all. Especially when the the country changes.

I tried to `explode(" ",$addr[0])`, it giving me the state on 0 and city on 1, but I try to use `explode(" ",$addr[6])`, It will give me `New` as a state and `York` as city. And same for UK and Canada zip code will be wrong.

My last question was marked duplicate, but my query is different and [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535809/extracting-city-and-zipcode-from-string-in-php) does not help me.

Comment: Your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66326887/extracting-state-city-and-zipcode-from-string-in-php) was flagged as too broad

Comment: I know, but some api or something exists that can validate it, I'm weak and I can't find a way to solve this problem.
I'm losing my reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate these strings into state city and zipcode, you will need to define rules that can apply to all of your strings.

If we separate them by space, New York is not gonna work since New York is a city but has space in the middle.
If we separate them by comma, some of them don't have comma.
If we separate by both space and comma, we cannot assume the last item will be zipcode since T5A 2L8 is zipcode but will be separated.

So there is no rule that I can think of that would work with your data. You should start from how these strings can be separated and identified. Try to apply it to the code and we will gladly help you.

Comment: I tried OSM nominatim, and that work perfectly, BTW I liked your answer as well :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use OSM nominatim, to separate and validate data.

Request

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=1&addressdetails=1&q=1088+Burton+Dr.+REDDING,+CA+96003+US

Response

```
[
    {
        "place_id": 266720693,
        "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
        "osm_type": "way",
        "osm_id": 10591437,
        "boundingbox": [
            "40.591203388592",
            "40.591303388592",
            "-122.34939939898",
            "-122.34929939898"
        ],
        "lat": "40.59125338859231",
        "lon": "-122.34934939898274",
        "display_name": "1088, Burton Drive, Lancer Hills Estates, Redding, Shasta County, California, 96003, United States",
        "class": "place",
        "type": "house",
        "importance": 0.621,
        "address": {
            "house_number": "1088",
            "road": "Burton Drive",
            "neighbourhood": "Lancer Hills Estates",
            "city": "Redding",
            "county": "Shasta County",
            "state": "California",
            "postcode": "96003",
            "country": "United States",
            "country_code": "us"
        }
    }
]
```

And this what I actually want, breaking down of the address string.